# How to make Microsoft.Extensions.Logging available for all classes

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I just started learning C#, and am redoing past Java projects. I am trying to use  Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, and I want to be able to make it available for all my classes in my console application.

Examples I referred to creates a LoggerFactory in the Main() method:
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/fundamentals-of-logging-in-dotnet-core
https://thecodeblogger.com/2021/05/11/how-to-enable-logging-in-net-console-applications/

How can I make MEL loggers available for all classes similar to how [log4net/serilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222160/singleton-logger-static-logger-factory-logger-how-to-log) does it? I did refer to [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line) but I m not very familiar with Dependency Injection in C#.

I could use log4net instead, however I saw a question thread on SO, that suggested it's better to program to an logging abstraction, as you can easily change logging providers later on depending on your needs.

ie:

```
class MyDomain
{
    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    private void SomeFunc()
    {
        _logger.Trace("this is a test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Dependency Injections is the ideal way (well, that doesn't mean other options are bad but i'd argue this is the right way to do it). Since you are learning, why not learn the DIs and they are ideal to start learning at this stage. If you do, MSFT's Logging extensions are best. You can then add any logging framework like Serilog, NLog (my always preferred) or others to enrich your logs to write to any platform as destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface that defines the methods that you want to use for logging.

eg

```
public interface ILog
{
    void LogInformation(string message);
    void LogWarning(string message);
    void LogError(string message);
}
```

Then you can implement this into a class where you are using  `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` to log.

```
public class Log : ILog
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Logger(ILogger<Logger> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void LogInformation(string message)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(message);
    }
}
```

Now you can use `ILog` in all the classes and in the future if you want to change the logging provider you can.

Note: This is a simple implementation. you can make this more dynamic depending on your needs.

Comment: does this require the dependency injection package? it looks really similar to the sample code provided on the microsoft documentation. How is it different?

Comment: Yes `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. You can also create logger factory as well.

Comment: So I assume: I would create the host, register services such as `IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).Build();`
Then I get the ILogger from DI,
`var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();` Then I pass it to the constructor shown in your sample code (for example)?

Comment: oh, i finally get it! I can use either the host, or non-hosting version to get an IHost or ILoggerFactory, then pass it to whatever class i need to create an instance of ILogger in that specific class!

Comment: Yes, you con go into more in detail about DI.